# Incorrect 'double' answer when dividing two 'int' number

Tags: java, int, double

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the basic concept of int and double. Could someone tell me, when I run the program, why 0.0 is printed out instead of 0.3333333?

```
    int i = 1;
    int j = 3;
    double k = i / j;
    System.out.println(k);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are doing integer division, which truncates the result to a integer.

You need to convert either one to double.

```
double k = i / (double)j;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
double k = i / j;
```

to

```
double k = (double)i / (double)j;
```

You need to **cast** one of the operands to `double` before dividing them.

Comment: No need cast both the int's. One will do :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't divide two integers and expect a double.

Declare them as `double`s to start with or cast them.

```
double k = (double)i / (double)j
//or
double i = 1;
double j = 3;
double k = i / j;
```